# CRM 2013 when deploying new customization's do plugins and work flows that have not changed need to be re deployed?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM 2013 when deploying  new customization's do plugins and workflows that have not changed need to be re deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not. Solution imports are additive. If you are moving your customizations via unmanaged solutions from a development to a production environment you do not need to include the plugins or processes if they are already in your production environment and have not been changed in the development environment.

For more information on solutions check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334576.aspx